# Getter without body, Setter with

Tags: c#, automatic-properties

I have a property which is currently automatic.

```
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

However, I now need it to perform some action every time it changes, so I want to add logic to the setter. So I want to do something like:

```
public string MyProperty {
    get;
    set { PerformSomeAction(); }
}
```

However, this doesn't build... `MyProperty.get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial`

I can't just have the getter return `MyProperty` as it will cause an infinite loop.

Is there a way of doing this, or do I have to declare a private variable to refer to? I'd rather not as `MyProperty` is used through out the code both in this class and outside it

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to use a property with backing field:

```
private string mMyProperty;
public string MyProperty
{
    get { return mMyProperty; }
    set
    {
        mMyProperty = value;
        PerformSomeAction();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is sad, isn't it. I mean why would they allow something like `string myStr { get; private set; }` but not `{ get; set { ... } }`.

Comment: @Parziphal Agree, it is really odd to allow one but not the other

Comment: it's simple, in the first case you have a backing field that is generated and you give them the responsibility to implement the setter and getter using it. In the second case you want a backing field in the get but not in the set, which is a problem. Otherwise it would beg the question- how will you modify the invisible backing field in the set?

Comment: @Evyatar It's simple, they already provide syntax for "value", you just add another syntax for the implicit backing field.

Answer (score 6):

You can´t implement one without the other, as when using the one it refers to a (hidden) backing-field which is auto-generated in the case of an autogenerated property. However when you implement one you have to set this backing-field in both ways.

The auto-way is just a shortcut for this:

```
private string _property;
public string MyProperty
{
    get { return _property; }
    set { _property = value; }
}
```

So if you´d omit the hidden field in one of the methods (this is what getters and setters are actually) how should this method know how to store/get the value?

Answer (score 2):

You need to either provide a body for both the getter and setter, or neither.

So if you define either one, it's no longer an auto property.

So you have to do:

Either

```
public string MyProperty {
    get;
    set;
}// Automatic property, no implementation
```

OR

```
public string MyProperty
{
    get { return mMyProperty; }
    set
    {
        mMyProperty = value;
        PerformSomeAction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing something in the setter then you will have to explicitly declare the variable. E.g.

```
private string _myProperty;
public string MyProperty {
    get { return _myProperty; };
    set 
    {
        _myProperty = value; 
        PerformSomeAction(); 
    }
}
```

or - in the setter you can pass value to the function and do what you want to it there... assuming you want to change/check the value in the function `PerformSomeAction()`

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the question [C# getter and setter shorthand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009823/c-sharp-getter-and-setter-shorthand).

When you manually specify a setter, it won't use the automatic property mechanism for the getter, which is why the error message acts like it's missing. You'll need to write your own getter when you specify the setter.